# $\bigcup_{\alpha\in C}\alpha A$ is compact in the topological vector space $X$

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space, with $A \subset X$ and $C \subset \mathbb{K}$ both compact subsets.

Why is $\bigcup_{\alpha\in C}\alpha A$ compact in $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cup_{\alpha \in C} \alpha A$ is the image of $C\times A$ under the continuous map $(c,y) \to cy$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $C\times A$ is compact in $\mathbb{K}\times X$ and multiplication by scalars is continuous.

Comment: Yes, we always have $C. A= \cup_{\alpha\in C}\alpha A$. But what if $A$ is just closed ?

Comment: @AnasBOUALII $A=X$ is closed and $C=\{1\}$ is compact.

Comment: Right, probably in case $A$ is closed, then $\cup_{\alpha\in C}\alpha A$ is closed too.